# Observer for import products

Tags: magento2, event-observer

I want to create an observer to execute when the import product is executing, i need persist product informations in another table when the export action is in process, i try the following:

> CatalogProductImportBunchSaveAfter

```
<?php
namespace Module\Imports\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Webkul\Marketplace\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;

class CatalogProductImportBunchSaveAfter implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface {
    protected $_objectManager;
    protected $_collectionFactory;
    protected $_date;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime $date,
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
    ) {
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->_collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        $this->_date = $date;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {


    //my logic to persist new data here;



    }
```

but, i dont now if this is ok. How can i recover all products informations on this observer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change observer class by following way:

```
<?php
namespace SR\MagentoCommunity\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;

class CatalogProductImportBunchSaveAfter implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $bunch = $observer->getEvent()->getData('bunch');
        foreach ($bunch as $rowNum => $rowData) {
            error_log(print_r($rowData,1)); // this is product information comes from csv row
        }
    }
}
```